# Simple C# Data Algorithms Question - Populate class from Exception class

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building this elobrate Logging solution for use in a government setting where things have to be done a certain way. One of the things is that we bubble up untrapped exceptions to the last point in Application_Error in global.asax where when of the things is that we get all the exceptions nested within the exception object and serialize that info to the database. There is code that walks the list. There is not one exception. There could be many nested exceptions. We build ASP.NET apps where we have this extensive bubble up exception logging system. A exception occurs. It bubbles up where another could happen, surrounding the other. It bubbles up to the last point - Application_Error in global.asax where there is all this logic that writes machine info to a database. An exception can occur during this which envelops the other exceptions

In my case, WCF is involved ONLY because the systems involved are in separate zones and WCF is used to communicate. and you CANNOT serialize/pass an .NET Exception object across the service boundary so I have defined a C# class/Data Structure to represent exceptions:

```
[DataContract]
public class ExceptionStructure
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<ExceptionStructure> InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

First, Whoa, this structure may not work since InnerException is READ ONLY so I need help on a new class as well. I need only the Message and StackTrace fields as well as InnerExceptions.

All I need help on is given an .NET exception object that may or may not have inner exceptions, can someone help me write the code that will populate one of these ExceptionStructure classes?

Also, code to deserialize one of these into a list of .NET exceptions on the other side would be nice? If you see a better structure idea, feel free.

Comment: Should InnerException not be of type `ExceptionStructure` instead of `List<ExceptionStructure>`? The inner exception can, after all, have its own inner exception as well. Also, you probably want to store the exception type in addition to the message.

Comment: The system has to gather exceptions on the way as it bubbles up and nest them as Inner Exceptions. I need some way of representing that.

Comment: In other words, loop until InnerExceptions = null.

Comment: @Sam: could you provide an example of what you mean by gathering exceptions as they bubble up? Are you saying that exceptions are being progressively wrapped as they traverse the call stack?

Comment: There is not one exception. There could be many nested exceptions. We build ASP.NET apps where we have this extensive bubble up exception logging system. A exception occurs. It bubbles up where another could happen, surrounding the other. It bubbles up to the last point - Application_Error in global.asax where there is all this logic that writes machine info to a database. An exception can occur during this which envelops the other exceptions.

Comment: @Sam: isn't there a single root Exception instance, or at worst, a collection of root Exceptions? Just serialize them on the one side and deserialize and log them on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with WCF [faults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx) ? You can use them to wrap exceptions and send them over the WCF wire:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
    int Divide(int n1, int n2);
}

public Calculator : ICalculator
{
    int Divide(int n1, int n2)
    {
        try
        {
            return n1/n2;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<DivideByZeroException>(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** In your case, since you are talking about a collection of exceptions, you could try faulting with an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383498.aspx)

Comment: I am and we are using them for one part of the solution. This is different.

Comment: Different because of the aggregation of exceptions? If so, see my edit

Comment: Nope. Look, I can't explain the security implications of the system and the DMZ and what systems are where. I just need an answer to the algorithm posed above.

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, exceptions can be serialized using .NET Runtime Serialization (`BinaryFormatter`, `SoapFormatter`). Why not serialize the exception into a byte array, send the byte array across the wire using WCF, then deserialize back into exception instances on the other side?

This will highlight the fact that this agency has chosen to depend on all exceptions always being serializable, but maybe that's ok.

Comment: There is not one exception. There could be many nested exceptions. We build ASP.NET apps where we have this extensive bubble up exception logging system. A exception occurs. It bubbles up where another could happen, surrounding the other. It bubbles up to the last point - Application_Error in global.asax where there is all this logic that writes machine info to a database. An exception can occur during this which envelops the other exceptions.

Comment: The only reason WCF is involved this time is that the ASP.NET system is outside the DMZ and is a client of the system inside the safe zone that contains Repositories and the database exposed via the WCF services. I am already using FaultContracts to capture exceptions that occur on the safe side. That's the first pass.

Comment: In that first pass, for security reasons, we can't leak out connection info and other exception info across the boundary. So we log it on the safe side. Pass 2, an exception occurs in the unsafe ASP.NET app side. The database for logging is inside the DMZ so there is an error logging service that this question is part of. I need to get that nested exception back over to log to the database along with all this machine info.

Comment: So, I just need a way to describe exceptions to get across the boundary in this error logging system. The other side already has these classes and methods to log exception info to the database or error log or file system. I just need a class/structure like above and an algorithm to poupulate it. Please.

Comment: @Sam, what does Application_Error see? A single Exception containing an InnerException that contains an InnerException, etc? Or maybe some of the exceptions contain a list of Exception instances? Doesn't matter. Serialize it and send it over, then deserialize it on the other side. The other side logs exceptions, right? Good: send them exceptions to log.

Comment: It sees a single Exception containing an Inner Exception that contains an InnerException, etc. Then please show me the code to walk the exception tree and serialize them.

Comment: @Sam: you should only need to serialize the top-level exception. It knows how to serialize its properties, including InnerException.