# How do you serialize an exception (with nested exceptions) using SOAP Formatter?

Tags: c#, .net

Editor controls missing from IE again...
Per this topic [Simple C# Data Algorithms Question - Populate class from Exception class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412653/simple-c-data-algorithms-question-populate-class-from-exception-class), at the bottom it was suggested that I use the .NET SOAPFormatter to serialize a *nested* tree of exceptions. How? Can anyone show me some code to do this (especially to walk the nested list of inner exceptions)? I need to see the actual code not just an API suggestion please.

I can't seem to respond to the answer or get the editor controls in my locked down IE 8, but I would like to see, in the code, a walk of the nested exceptions by travsering the InnerException property and the exception added. I would like to see a MemoryStream used and the SOAPformatter.

Answer (score 1):

This should make the point:

```
    private static void BinaryFormatterDemo()
    {

        // serialise 
        Exception ex = new Exception("Some message",
            new Exception("Another message"));
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ex.bin", FileMode.Create);
        bf.Serialize(fs, ex);
        fs.Close();


        // deserialise
        fs = new FileStream("ex.bin", FileMode.Open);
        Exception loadedEx = (Exception) bf.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine(loadedEx);
        fs.Close();


    }
```

`SoapFormatter` is no different, just change `BinaryFormatter` with `SoapFormatter`.